# Angularjs: directive updates view after user logs in

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've got an app with a login screen and a widget on the site showing the user's favorite items in the site.

in the site html

```
<header data-ng-controller="SideBarController">
    <section id="sidebar">
        <div sidebar-user-info></div>
        <div sidebar-my-favorites-list></div>
        <p class="full"><a href="#/logout">logout</a></p>
    </section>
</header>
```

the inline template block

```
<script id="sideBarFavoritesList_template" type="text/ng-template">
    <ul id="my-favorites" class="full no-bullets">
        <li data-ng-repeat="fav in myFavorites">
            <a href="#" id="{{fav.id}}"><img ng-src="/gfx/apps/icons{{ fav.icon }}" width="36" height="36" alt="{{ fav.name }} icoon" class="favicon">{{ fav.name }}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</script>
```

I've got then a directive rendering the widget

```
App.directive('sidebarMyFavoritesList', ['$rootScope', function sideBarMyfavoritesList($rootScope) {
    return {
        template: $('#sideBarFavoritesList_template').html(),
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true
    };
}]);
```

The controller surrounding the entire sidebar

```
function SideBarController($http, $scope, $rootScope, helper, UserService)
{
    $rootScope.user = UserService.data;
    $rootScope.loggedIn = UserService.isLogged;

    $scope.toggleBar = function toggleBar() {
        if (!UserService.isLogged) {
            return;
        }
        $rootScope.state.appbar = !$rootScope.state.appbar;
    };

    var serviceUrl = "/api/favorites/user";
    $http.get(serviceUrl).success(function(d) {
        $scope.myFavorites = d.data;
    });
}
```

now, the `UserService` is updated when the user logs in, however the sidebar is always there. what I want is that the sidebar refreshes itself and renders the user's favorites.

it works for the user info, as i found myself using the rootScope for that, after the user logs in successfully i update the user object on the rootScope. but that feels very hacky.

the way i see it, i would have to redo the ajax call to that service, after the user is logged in, but i have no idea where that should be done.

if i refresh the page after login it works instantly because the user session is available at the server side at start of the initial page load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your UserService updates $rootScope.user you can siply watch $rootScope.user from your SideBarController and update $scope.myFavorites.

Comment: it feels hacky, I was searching for an event system in angular like backbone has, because basing it on the rootScope.user is a dependency I didn't want to make, but you are right about the solution, if I watch that user object I can make it work. I'm just not sure if it's the best way possible :)

Comment: You can use $scope.$emit() and $scope.$on() as event system.

Comment: hm thanks for that, i'd have to use the $rootScope for that though, as a global event aggregator. as i believe it would be impossible to use the local $scope for that especially if you are listening to shared events over multiple directives ... but still thanks for the tip...

Answer (score 0):

Your `UserService.data` should return an object literal. Looking at your code, I can't be sure if it is a string or an object literal that it is returning.  It is important that it is an object literal, because then you can pass by reference, and the same reference can be used to bind to independent scopes.  Binding to rootScope becomes unnecessary.

**Service:**

```
app.factory('UserService', function() {
     var user = {};
     var serviceUrl = "/api/favorites/user";
         $http.get(serviceUrl).success(function(d) {
         angular.extend(user,d.data);
     });

     return {
        data:user        
     };
});
```

**SideBarController:**

```
app.controller('SideBarController', function($scope, UserService) {
      $scope.loginInfo = UserService.data;
});
```

The important points to note about this solution:

1. UserService (like all services) are singletons - meaning one instance is shared between all controllers and directives.
2. UserService.data returns an empty object literal initially, but then updates it after calling `$http.get` asynchronously.
3. All properties (including `loggedIn`) are stored within the object literal. This is so that we never pass by value when binding to the scope.
4. All scope bindings are by reference (not by value).  So when the UserService.data changes, it will automatically update all independent scopes that are watching it.
5. rootScope is never required.

I prefer this approach as it is more modular with fewer external dependencies (i.e. on root scope).